# Proving the parallelity of two lines in a convex Pentagon

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Can someone show me how to solve this Geometry Problem? I feel like there is a trick behind it that I don’t see

The convex pentagon $ABCDE$ has a circumference and $\overline{AB} = \overline{BD}$ applies. Let the point $P$ be the intersection of the diagonals $AC$ and $BE$. The straight lines $BC$ and $DE$ intersect at point $Q$.
Prove that the line $PQ$ is parallel to the diagonal $AD$.

Comment: Something is missing. Why do you say it has a circumference? As stated, you could slide C back and forth along BQ, or slide E along DQ, without moving anything else except P. So P has two degrees of freedom while A, D, and Q stay fixed. So what you want to prove is not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$AB = BD$ implies that their corresponding circular arcs are equal too, so $EB$ is the angle bisector of $\angle \, AED$ and thus $\angle \, AEB = \angle \, DEB$. Let $R$ be the intersection point of $BE$ and $AD$. Then, after a short angle chasing, triangles $AEP$ and $BEQ$ are similar, so
$$\frac{EP}{EQ} = \frac{EA}{EB}$$
and triangles $AER$ and $BED$ are similar, so
$$\frac{ER}{ED} = \frac{EA}{EB}$$
Consequently,
$$\frac{EP}{EQ} = \frac{EA}{EB} = \frac{ER}{ED}$$
which by the Thales' intercept theorem yields
$$RD \, || \, PQ$$ and since $R$ lies on $AD$ you get
$$AD \, || \, PQ$$

Answer (score 2):

Observe that,  $\triangle AEP\sim \triangle BEQ$ and hence $\angle APE=\angle BQE$. From here,  it is seen that quadrilateral $PCQE$ is cyclic.

Thus, $\angle CPQ=\angle CEQ=\angle CED=\angle CAD$ and therefore $PQ\parallel AD$.